# Access 2016 - Lookup wizard returning the incorrect value

Tags: ms-access-2016

I used the 'Lookup Wizard' to try and create a drop-down list to show the IDs stored in another table, I need the drop-down to also list the employee name so I know what number to select, all of that works, however, when I select the item I need it returns the employee name, not the number. I am new to Access and I hope there is a simple solution for this. 
[image: Screen Shot - Field Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Column Widths** property to: `0;1"`

This will hide the first column whilst still retaining the link between primary & foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I had to switch the select statement to: SELECT [Employee Info].[Vendor ID], [Employee Info].[Employee Name]